# Pyspark trying to write to DB2 table - truncate overwrite

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, db2

I am trying to write the data to IBM DB2 (10.5 fix pack 11) using Pyspark (2.4).
When I try to execute below piece of code

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
.mode('overwrite').option("url",'jdbc:db2://<host>:<port>/<DB>').
option("driver", 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver').
option('sslConnection', 'true')
.option('sslCertLocation','</location/***_ssl.crt?').
option("numPartitions", 1).
option("batchsize", 1000)
.option('truncate','true').
option("dbtable", '<TABLE>').
option("user",'<user>').
option("password", '<PW>')
.save()
```

job is throwing the following exception:

> File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
> occurred while calling o97.save. :
> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error:
> SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601,
> SQLERRMC=END-OF-STATEMENT;ABLE<SEHEMA.TABLE>;IMMEDIATE, DRIVER=4.19.80
> at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.b5.a(b5.java:747)

Job is trying to perform truncate but seems like DB2 is expecting ** IMMEDIATE** keyword

In my above code all I am passing is only name of the dbtable, is there a way to pass
IMMEDIATE keyword?

And also from DB2 side, is there a way to set this while opening the session?

Just FYI, my code with out truncate works, but that delete the table and recreates and loads, I don't want to do that on prod environment.

Any thoughts on how to solve this issue are highly appreciated.

Comment: if the spark dialect for Db2 will not currently generate the `immediate` keyword, consider a workaround.  For Db2-LUW you can call a stored procedure to do the work for you. If your account authorisations are correct, you can use a  pre-existing procedure like this: `CALL ADMIN_CMD('IMPORT FROM /dev/null OF DEL REPLACE INTO your_schema.your_table_name ')` . This was how to do an unlogged empty-table on Db2-LUW before the truncate ... immediate syntax was added.

Answer (score 1):

[DB2Dialect](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/DB2Dialect.scala) in Spark 2.4 doesn't override the default `JDBCDialect`'s implementation of a TRUNCATE TABLE. Comments in [the code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JdbcDialects.scala#L132) suggest to override this method to return a statement that suits your database engine.

```
  /**
   * The SQL query that should be used to truncate a table. Dialects can override this method to
   * return a query that is suitable for a particular database. For PostgreSQL, for instance,
   * a different query is used to prevent "TRUNCATE" affecting other tables.
   * @param table The table to truncate
   * @param cascade Whether or not to cascade the truncation
   * @return The SQL query to use for truncating a table
   */
  @Since("2.4.0")
  def getTruncateQuery(
    table: String,
    cascade: Option[Boolean] = isCascadingTruncateTable): String = {
      s"TRUNCATE TABLE $table"
  }
```

Perhaps in DB2 case you can actually extend `DB2Dialect` itself, add your getTruncateQuery() implementation and define your "custom" JDBC protocol, `"jdbc:mydb2"` for example. You can then use this protocol in JDBC connection URL, `.option("url",'jdbc:mydb2://<host>:<port>/<DB>')`.

Comment: Which means I need to build and use my own version of spark code base as well, ours is AWS Glue env, I will explore the feasibilities, thanks for your time

Comment: Not really, you can just build a jar with your own dialect class in it, and load it along with your db2 jdbc driver. I hope glue has some support for bringing your own, non-OOTB databases (although I'm no aws expert). Good luck!

Comment: great thank you for the tip, and Glue has provision to add user jars.